Authetication using Go Routers with flutter
class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService authService = AuthService();
    final userProvider = context.read<UserProvider>();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await authService.getUserData(context: context);

      if (userProvider.userModel.token.isNotEmpty) {
        context.go(AppRouterName.homeView.path);
      } else {
        context.go(AppRouterName.signInView.path);
      }
    });

    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}

I was trying go routers with flutter.
I am also doing back-end operations with node.js.
When the application is opened, if the user has logged in before, open HomeView, if not, open signUpView.
The code above works. But I think it is a very amateur code. Thanks to those who helped.

Use redirect in your GoRoute definition.

I would try to create StreamSubscription what listen on authorisation state  changes and navigate to desired screen depending on emitted state.
